# How to start and stop jobs externally running with @Scheduled(fixedDelay) annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for some solution for starting and stopping the jobs where methods are annotated with @Scheduled(fixedDelay).
I am working on a spring boot project and this application is standalone with no front end. 
I have looked into web put not able to understand what they are trying to say.

Basically i want to stop and start my application externally via some url.

Comment: stop and start spring boot jar? or @Scheduled annotation method?

Comment: Annotation method

Comment: In that case you don't want to start and stop the _application_ via some URL, you just want to start and stop the annotated method. Why don't you just create another controller URL endpoint and use the same service method that your `@Scheduled` method uses.

Comment: what about if i want to stop spring boot jar?